# aria-label, aria-labelledby and aria-describedby: very unforeseeable behaviour in screenreaders

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader, nvda

I just noticed that although the `aria-label`, `aria-labelledby` and `aria-describedby` attributes are said to work on every element (see https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-1.1/states_and_properties#aria-describedby), they only seem to work for a few elements like `a`, and not for e.g. `div` or `p` in NVDA and JAWS.

I have created a small codepen to demonstrate the issue (browse it using browse and focus mode):

https://codepen.io/jmuheim/pen/avWbPe

For example, in NVDA, on the `a` element, the `aria-label` and `aria-labelledby` seem to work in both browse and focus mode. But `aria-describedby` is only announced in focus mode, not in browse mode.

For the `input` element, none of the attributes seem to work in browse mode, but all work in focus mode.

For "bare" text elements like `p` or `div`, none of the attributes seem to work.

In JAWS, it's quite similar behaviour, but at least for the `p` element, when there is an `aria-describedby`, it announces that a description can be read by pressing "JAWS + alt + r".

I don't really see a clear pattern for this, so I wonder what are the general rules in screenreaders on how to use these attributes? Or better: why don't they simply work for every element, as the spec proposes?

Comment: Great article by Léonie Watson on The Paciello Group's website about this: https://www.tpgi.com/short-note-on-aria-label-aria-labelledby-and-aria-describedby/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ARIA does not define how assistive tech are to expose UI. It does define how [browsers are required](http://www.w3.org/TR/core-aam-1.1/) to expose roles, states and properties via accessibility APIs. It's the same with HTML in general, the HTML spec does not define/require UI, that is left up to the browsers to decide. 
In the case of aria-label (for example) it is a requirement in ARIA that aria-label is mapped to the accessible name property in [accessibility APIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/core-aam-1.1/#intro_aapi), it is not a requirment that screen readers announce it, or not, on any given element (i.e. expose as part of the aural UI).
General observed rule is that screen readers will announce [accessible names and accessible descriptions](http://www.w3.org/TR/core-aam-1.1/#mapping_additional_nd) on [interactive elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content). They will announce accessible names on most [grouping elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#grouping-content) and [sectioning elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#sectioning-content). They will announce **neither** on most [text level elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#text-level-semantics).

**Note:** the above also applies to any element that has it's default semantics overidden with ARIA roles. For example [ARIA widget roles](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#widget_roles) will have both acc name and description announced, like native HTML interactive elements.

Comment: Thanks for explaining and providing sources. I asked the [same question on the NVDA issue tracker](http://community.nvda-project.org/ticket/5398), there's some information specific to NVDA, too.